# How do you do the Kaioken with base Goku in Hyper DBZ Mugen Champ's edition + Super Buu?

Tags: pc, mugen

In the game "Hyper DBZ Mugen Champ's edition + Super Buu" you can make several special moves which each character, with base Goku you can do the kamehameha, the instant transmition, rapid fire, and others. But once (only once) I made the kaioken by accident, which it seems to be base Goku best move, and I dont know how I did it, and I couldnt repeat it again by accident either. I looked in internet, but I couldnt find it how to do it.

How do you do the Kaioken with base Goku in Hyper DBZ Mugen Champ's edition + Super Buu?